# Grouping SQL Server Connections By Connection Pool

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling

In SQL Server 2014 is there a way to group connections by the connection pool that belong to? We are trying to find out if a specific application is leaking connections and hitting the default max pool size of 100.

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) doc on Connection Pooling it states that each pool is defined by the exact connection string used to establish the connection. However, I am unable to find anything in the sys table that allows me to see that.

The closest I have groups by loginname and program_name:

```
select  rtrim(p.loginame) 
    ,p.program_name
    ,count(*)
from    sys.sysprocesses p   
group by p.loginame, p.program_name
order by count(*) desc
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd start with the queries here: https://sqlperformance.com/2017/07/sql-performance/find-database-connection-leaks

Answer (score 1):

You can get a little closer if you add host process id but I don't think you'll be able to get an actual connection pool count 100% from server data because many connection string attributes are processed on the client and never sent to the server. This might be close enough for your needs, though.

```
SELECT
      s.login_name
    , s.host_name
    , s.program_name
    , s.host_process_id
    , COUNT(*) AS connection_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
GROUP BY
      s.login_name
    , s.host_name
    , s.program_name
    , s.host_process_id;
```

A client-side exception like "timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool" should be raised when the pool size is reached an another connection cannot be acquired within the connection timeout limit.